# Getting path to other than starting project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a start up project called Admin. It calls a method in another project called Data. Data reads an XML located in the folder Data.dll is in. But the path i get is wrongly looking in the Admin project folder.

Ive tried (from ther Data project )

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"BookSource\Book.Xml");
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"BookSource\", "Book.Xml")
```

Both of them looks in 
..Admin\Bin\Debug\BookSource\Book.Xml 
instead of 
..Data\Bin\Debug\BookSource\Book.Xml

I assume its because Admin starts the solution. So how can i get the path to another project than the starting project?

Comment: can't you just go up one level to your solution folder? `"..\"` will go up one level, then you can add the path to the correct project.

Comment: I guess so. But how is it supposed. To be done?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your XML file is marked as "Copy Always" in its properties and then just use the filename.  When the DLL from your data project is coppied into the bin directory of your Admin project, this setting will let the compiler know that it should also make a copy of the XML file in the destination location.

In solution explorer, right click your XML file and choose properties
[image: Solution Explorer, xml file context sensitive menu, click Properties]

Now under **Copy to Output Directory** choose *Copy always*

[image]

In my Class1.cs example I have the following code which returns true when called from Program.cs:

```
public static bool LookForFile()
{
    return File.Exists("XMLFile1.xml");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about the copy options. This still doesnt help me. I have the XML in the Data project. But since it is TestPaths project that starts and calls Data project the XML.Load("XMLFile1.xml") looks for the file at TestPaths\Bin\Debug\XMLFile1.xml. 

Is there a way to get the Data projects own path no matter which project starts?

Comment: In the example above, the XML file is part of the data project but the code show is in the TestPaths project.  The XML file is automatically brought into the TestPaths\Bin\Debug directory when the Data.dll file is brought in.  The source of truth for the file is still the Data project, but an instance is available for the TestPaths project during debugging or running.